# Arduino help adding a second mpu 6050 sensor my working code

Tags: i2c, mpu6050

Background information: I currently have this arduino code that uses one mpu 6050 sensor to get angles in the x, y, and z directions and then display them to the user nicely. Code can be found here [basic MPU 6050 code](http://myecworks.blogspot.com/2016/09/measuring-inclination-angle.html)

The problem: **I would like to add a second mpu 6050** to my project and average the values from the two mpu 6050s.

I know how to physically wire the second sensor into the project but don't know how to do the coding side of things. The code I have is below. Any help is greatly appreciated. This is a very fun tool.

```
#include<Wire.h>
const int MPU_addr=0x68;
int16_t axis_X,axis_Y,axis_Z;
int minVal=265;
int maxVal=402;
double x;
double y;
double z;

void setup(){
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x6B);
  Wire.write(0);
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x3B);
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU_addr,14,true);
  axis_X=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();
  axis_Y=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();
  axis_Z=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();
    int xAng = map(axis_X,minVal,maxVal,-90,90);
    int yAng = map(axis_Y,minVal,maxVal,-90,90);
    int zAng = map(axis_Z,minVal,maxVal,-90,90);
       x= RAD_TO_DEG * (atan2(-yAng, -zAng)+PI);
       y= RAD_TO_DEG * (atan2(-xAng, -zAng)+PI);
       z= RAD_TO_DEG * (atan2(-yAng, -xAng)+PI);
     Serial.print("Angle of inclination in X axis = ");
     Serial.print(x);
     Serial.println((char)176);
     Serial.print("Angle of inclination in Y axis= ");
     Serial.print(y);
     Serial.println((char)176);
     Serial.print("Angle of inclination in Z axis= ");
     Serial.print(z);
     Serial.println((char)176);
     Serial.println("-------------------------------------------");
     delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Run a i2c scanner and tell us if two sensors are found. Why do you request 14 bytes and then use only 6 bytes? You could try a utf-8 character ° instead of (char)176.

Answer (score 1):

Ok first did YOU wiring theme correctly? Because the mpu use i2c BUS . 
Second this code from gitlab it may help you . 
https://gitlab.com/shuvashish/batikkrom.com/blob/master/MuttipleMPU/MuttipleMPU.ino
Check it . And use it

Comment: Did you write that code? The lines with the while statement should be remove and 0x00000000 is not a byte.